# Why can't all instances of vector fields be integrated?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The vector field produced by  xi +  yj  is a gradient field with a potential function.  When integrated this potential function produced the gradient and it can be show it has a 0 curl which is both a necessary and sufficient condition. The gradient is an exact differential. It can be shown that an inexact differential will never produce a gradient field.  Now consider <-y,x> ( i.e. -yi + yj ) which is NOT an  exact differential and this can be easily shown and if it  were an inexact differential then it can be easily seen that its curl would be non zero. But it is not that exact or inexact.  My problem is that I do not understand how it can be shown that for <-y,x> not only is it not an exact or inexact differential but it appears to me to be NO type of differential at all. My question: How can this be shown and ( this is the most important part ) How is it that the fact that there is NO differential results in a curl in the vector field?  A geometric intuition would be nice.  I asked this question in a different guise but perhaps and with  all due respects some clever person will be able to come down to my junior level and explain it to me. What prompted the question was that I was trying to reverse engineer <-y,x> to see if I could find a function that would be an inexact differential to prove a non zero curl but I could not find one, I assumed there was none and then asked myself, why not? Thus you see the question above "Why can't all instances of vector fields be integrated. The example serves as something you can hopefully get your teeth into.

Comment: It would be nice if this was divided into paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of the question is really obscure, but here I try anyway:

We compute and see that if curl of a vector field that comes from deriving a real-valued function is always zero.

So, when we are given a random vector field, in order for it to have come from a gradient, it has to have zero curl. This is a necessary condition.

Comment: Almost, you are almost there. Use this example <-y,x>. We need to show there is no real valued function that you can differentiate and come up with  <-y,x> . The rest is easy since only an exact differential can have a 0 curl. <-y,x> does not have a 0 curl. Please show me why it is impossible for it to the result of differentiating  a real valued function.  That is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: You're saying that $<-y,x>$ does not have a $0$ curl. Had it been the gradient of some real function $f$, i.e. $D f = <-y,x>$, then we would have $\curl <-y,x> = \curl D f =0$. Since this is not the case, such an $f$ can't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I like to envision the process like this:
$$ \left\{\text{scalar valued functions} \right\} \overset{gradient}{\longrightarrow} \{\text{vector fields} \} \overset{curl}{\longrightarrow} \{\text{vector fields}\} \overset{div}{\longrightarrow} \{\text{scalar valued functions} \} $$

I.e., $\nabla$ inputs a scalar valued function $f$ and outputs a vector field $\nabla f$, or $\nabla \times \bullet $ inputs a vector field and returns a new vector field.

It can easily be shown that the composition of  curl with gradient or the composition of divergence with curl produces the appropriate zero. For example,

$$\nabla \times (\nabla f) = \nabla \times \langle f_x, f_y, f_z \rangle= \langle f_{zy} - f_{yz} , f_{xz}-f_{zx}, f_{yx}-f_{xy} \rangle = \langle 0,0,0\rangle
$$
where the last inequality depends on Clairaut's Theorem being satisfied. As such, if we take a vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ and find that $\nabla\times\vec{F}=\vec{0}$, we know that $\vec{F}$ is in the image of the gradient operator and so there must exist $f$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$. Conversely, If $\nabla \times \vec{F} \neq \vec{0}$, then there is no scalar valued $f$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$.

Analogously, if we are given a vector field $\vec{F}$, we can ask if there's a vector field $\vec{G}$ such that $\nabla \times \vec{G} = \vec{F}$. A suitable condition to check this is if $\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = 0$, since it would necessarily be true that $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{G}) =0$.

There are a few technical points in the background (we need everything to be suitably differentiable / smooth, need suitable domains for all of our functions), but that is the general idea. This sort of thinking actually leads to the usual capstones of a vector calculus course--Green's Theorem, Stoke's Theorem, and the Divergence (Gauss-Ostrogradsky) Theorem. Loosely speaking, Green's/Stoke's Theorems ask by how much a vector field fails to be conservative (i.e., how far a vector field is from the image of the gradient operator), while the Divergence Theorem asks by how much a vector field fails to have a "vector gradient" (i.e., how far a vector field is from the image of the curl operator)

**Edit**

**Example #1**

Let $\vec{F}(x,y) = \langle y , x \rangle$. Seek $f(x,y)$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$.

If such an $f(x,y)$ existed, then $f_x (x,y) = y$ and $f_y(x,y) = x$. Integrating each expression with respect to the appropriate variable yields

\begin{align*}
f_x (x,y) = y &\implies f(x,y) = \int y ~\mathrm{d} x = xy + g(y) \\
f_y(x,y) = x &\implies f(x,y) = \int x ~\mathrm{d} y = xy + h(x) 
\end{align*}
Where $g(y)$ and $h(x)$ are arbitrary functions of $y$ and $x$ respectively. Since these two expressions are supposed to both be $f(x,y)$, we need to choose $g(y)$ and $h(x)$ such that $xy+ g(y) = xy + h(x)$ and the only possibility is that $g(y) = h(x) = C$ for some constant $C$. Therefore, $f(x,y) = xy + C$ is a potential function for $\vec{F}(x,y) = \langle y , x \rangle$.

To see that such an $f(x,y)$ exists without finding it directly, we can note that $\vec{F}(x,y) = \langle y,x \rangle$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $\tilde{F}(x,y,z) = \langle y , x, 0 \rangle$. Then $\nabla \times \tilde{F} = \langle 0, 0, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} y \rangle =\langle 0, 0,  1-1 \rangle =\vec{0}  $ and that the domain of $\vec{F}$ or $\tilde{F}$ is suitably nice (in this case simply connected). Thus, there is no contradiction that there might exist an $f$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$, as $\vec{0} = \nabla \times (\nabla f) = \nabla \times \vec{F} = \vec{0}$.

**Example #2**

Let $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = \langle -y , x , 0 \rangle$. We hope to find $f(x,y,z)$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$. As in the previous example, we proceed by direct computation:
\begin{align*}
f_x = -y &\implies f = \int -y ~\mathrm{d}x = -xy + g_1(y,z) \\
f_y = x &\implies f= \int x ~\mathrm{d} y = xy + g_2 (x,z) \\
f_z = 0 &\implies f= \int 0 ~\mathrm{d} z = g_3(x,y)
\end{align*}
where $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are arbitrary functions of their respective variables. However, all three expressions on the RHS are supposed to be the same function and there is no way to pick $g_1,g_2,g_3$ such that they are equal--a contradiction! Therefore, no such $f$ exists.

Alternatively, we can show that no such $f$ exists without actually trying to compute it (integration is hard!). Again, **if** there exists $f$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{F}$, **then** $\nabla \times (\nabla f) = \nabla \times \vec{F} = \vec{0}$. However,

$$\nabla \times \vec{F} = \langle 0,0,2 \rangle \neq \vec{0}$$

Again, noting that the domain of $\vec{F}$ is suitably nice (simply connected), we can conclude that no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Great answer!!! =)

Comment: Nice summary, I will have to take time to digest it. I was wondering if you can be so kind to show me why there does not exist a function  for <-y,x> that can be integrated to be either an exact or inexact differential.  It graph  goes round a swirl in a counter clockwise position.  I think illustrating with an example  may help me at this point.  Thank you.

Comment: oops...I made a type ...should be "from either an exact or inexact differential" instead of "to be".   Sorry